# How to use a capture specific strings in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

Below is my regular expression:

```
Function1(.*?)(google)((.|\n|\r)*?)LAST\);
```

I want to capture this entire function that includes spaces,newlines etc. I have bunch of functions inside my script but want to specifically capture function that contains "google" from entire list.

```
Function1("query", 
    "URL=https://clients1.google.com/tbproxy/af/query?client=Google+Chrome&q=Chc2LjEuMTcxNS4xNDQyL2VuIChHR0xMKRMZPd2PDK1PW1YjLQScNYckIy0DFGhXJCMt1XOH3CQjLd4_k74kIy1QDijrJCMtdQCYzyQjLRkUiZIkIy3xrEvRJCMtc6vwHyQjLa44BcEkIy0ghfciJCMtgsHVLSQU", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "Resource=1", 
    "RecContentType=text/proto", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t103.inf", 
    LAST);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that no regular expression will support back-quotes in your string arguments.

Comment: That is, no regex that you'd want to write. It's certainly possible though. Witness this JSON parser: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856

Answer (score 4):

I think I might do this with two patterns. The first extracts the stuff between the function parentheses and the second checks if that has `google` in it:

```
my $pattern = qr/
    Function1\( (.*?) LAST\);
        /sx;

if( $string =~ $pattern and $1 =~ /google\.com/ ) {
    ...
    }
else {
    say "No match!";
    }
```

The problem with the regex approach is that you have to work extra hard to ensure that the part of the pattern that ends the function call doesn't also appear in the data. That is, if `LAST);` can be in one of those fields, this may fail. At that point you'll have better luck with something that parses the string step-by-step.

---

Here's a much more complicated answer that uses a powerful but often neglected parsing feature of regular expressions.

- A global match, `/g`, in scalar context remembers its ending position in the string.
- You can see that position with `pos()`
- The `\G` anchors the next part of the match at `pos()`
- The `/c` option tells the match operator to not reset the position if the match fails
- With multiple regexes and `/c` you can try different things until one of them works.

Here's a small demonstration of that. There's an outer `if` that checks that you're inside a function call. Once inside that `if` block, keep looping (here with `redo`, but that's just one way) while additional patterns can match. When you match the pattern for the end of the function call, break out of the loop (`last`).

The meat is the pattern that looks for things inside parentheses. That pattern starts and ends with `"`, then looks for characters that aren't quotes or for escaped quotes. This is the improvement from my previous program because the pattern won't terminate earlier than you intended. Note that I adjusted the URL value to have escaped quotes and `LAST);`, which would cause my prior solution to fail (maybe as a false positive).

There's another benefit. I know which key in the function call has which value and all that ends up in a hash. If keys other than `URL` contained the string `google` you might get other false positives with my prior solutions:

```
$_ = <<'HERE';
Function1("query",
    "URL=https://\"LAST);clients1.goggle.com/tbproxy...",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "Resource=1",
    "RecContentType=text/proto",
    "Referer=",
    "Snapshot=t103.inf",
    LAST);
HERE


my %hash;
if( / Function1 \( \s* /xg ) {
    LOOP: {
        if( / \G LAST \s* \) \s* ; /xgc ) {
            say "Matched end";
            last;
            }

        if( / \G " ( (?: [^"] | \\ " )+ ) " , \s* /xgc ) {
            my $found = $1;
            my( $field, $value ) = split /=/, $found, 2;
            $hash{$field} = $value;
            redo;
            }

        warn "Shouldn't be here!\n";
        }
    }

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( \%hash );
```

Improve that by hiding it all in a subroutine (a good practice no matter which solution you use).

```
if( is_google($string) ) { say "Found Google" }
else                     { say "Didn't find Google" }

sub is_google {
    my( $string ) = @_;

    my %hash;
    if( / Function1 \( \s* /xg ) {
        LOOP: {
            if( / \G " ( (?: [^"] | \\ " )+ ) " , \s* /xgc ) {
                my $found = $1;
                my( $field, $value ) = split /=/, $found, 2;
                $hash{$field} = $value;
                redo;
                }

            if( / \G LAST \s* \) \s* ; /xgc ) {
                say "Matched end";
                last;
                }

            warn "Shouldn't be here!\n";
            }
        }

    return $hash{URL} =~ /google\.com/ ? 1 : ();
    }
```

Comment: What does `.*?`? A random character zero or more times. And this again zero or one time?

Comment: The `*` quantifier normally matches 0 or more times _greedily_... meaning it will consume as many characters as it can. Adding the question mark makes it a non-greedy match. For example, `'ababa' =~ /(a.*ba)/` matches the whole string, but `'ababa' =~ /(a.*?ba)/` only matches `aba`. Search [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for `*?`, as well as it's counter-point `*+` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

really ugly version, but catches what you need:
`Function1([^\n]*\n+)+(.*?)URL=(.*?)google.com(.*)([^\n]*\n+)+(.*)`
hopefully others can improve this, but you have a starting point